# How to stop macOS Monterey from moving windows to a single space when monitors change?

Tags: macos, mac

I recently bought a new MacBook and I'm having an issue I haven't seen before. Whenever I plug in — or unplug — my external monitor, every window is moved to the current Space that I'm on.

This simply seems like a bug. Why would I want all my windows to be rearranged?

I tried to turn off as many apps as I could and the issue still persists. Is this an issue for others?

Here's an example, in case my explanation isn't clear enough:

- I have 4 spaces open
- Say notes and calculator are currently space 1
- I'm on space 2, and there is only keynote on that space.
- When I plug in my monitor, everything is now on space 2.
- With the same setup, and my external monitor first plugged in, unplugging it will have the same effect

I'm guessing the issue is Monterey but maybe something else is happening?

Comment: Check the status of "Displays have separate spaces" & see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/430798/mac-forgets-window-workspace-association-on-monitor-disconnect/430799#430799 [I don't think this answers your question, but it may help accurately diagnose whether it's a bug or not. I don't have access to Monterey.]

Comment: Thanks! I've tried it with and without that checked and still have the same problem.

Comment: Have a look at the link again. The OP on there seems to have fixed it with an OS update. I can’t test, not on Monterey yet.

Comment: Oh my gosh, you are right! I just updated and that fixed the problem, thank you! Did you want to answer the question or should I?

Comment: Go for it. I don't need the points ;))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update from Monterey 12.0.0 to 12.0.1, and this will be fixed!